# Direct back substitution disregarding change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

The solution to this definite integration problem involves considering $t=1/y$ to make a change of the integration bounds. However after solving in terms of $y$ they directly substitute back into $t$ disregarding the earlier substitution.

Shouldn't it be substituted back as $y=1/t$ when or why can we just replace a variable with another like that?

Comment: The point is $\int_a^bf(u)\mathrm{d}u=\int_a^bf(v)\mathrm{d}v$; $u,\,v$ are just letters you can change whenever you like. We're not committed to old definitions of letters if we want to bring them back after a substitution.

Answer (score 1):

This works because $y$ and $t$ are just variables that we can arbitrarily change, after the substitution:

$$\int^x_1 \frac{\log y}{y(1+y)}dy \equiv \int^x_1 \frac{\log t}{t(1+t)}dt$$

And so the two integrals can be summed together. Hope this helps.

Comment: So can this work in any definite integration regardless of the bounds ? For example if I make a substitution in an integral then after solving I can directly swap the new variable for the old one without worrying about how I defined it first?

Comment: @user396087 You would have to change the integral bounds accordingly first, before swapping the variables